# Filtering data and displaying only required part of the data

Tags: json, node.js

I have data in json and want the filtered data in node.js.
The data in json is pasted below i want to display only those data which has set_account:false.

```js
{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
      {"name":"idea"},
        {"set_account":"false"},
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"name":"idea"},
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        null,
        {"name":"airtel"},
        {"set_account":"false"},
        {"id": "Quality"},
        {"id": "Pause"},
        {"id": "Mute"},
        null,
        {"name":"vodafone"},
        {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
        {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
        {"id": "Copy"},
        {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
        {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
        {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
        null,
        {"name":"jio"},
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}
```

## EDIT: After so long I came across this post which I posted in my initial days of coding, in comments I saw  @wscourge and @Sadhu were right and the answer accepted below was what I was looking for.

I don't remember what I had done that time but I guess I had changed the JSON format that time which would have worked for me.

Note: Just posting this update so that anyone coming across this could know.

Comment: Show us your attempts? We can't just do your requirements for you

Comment: `{"set_account":"false"}` are standalone objects in your `menu.items` array. *Those data which has `set_account: false`* results in those objects, will not do you any good with this JSON structure, as all you'd get would be those single-field objects. Try `menu.items.filter(item => item.set_account === false)` and see it for yourself.

Comment: Your json schema is wrong.

Comment: @Sadhu is right, the schema is wrong. But do you want to filter the items separated by `null` value?. Could you post an example of what result you expect from the filtering?

Comment: eg: ["name":"idea","set_account":"false"]  i am expecting this as output

Comment: i used this as reference but this only shows the first value found but i want all the possible values to be found.                                                 
    var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 8}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array.filter :

```js
var inventory = [{
  name: 'apples',
  quantity: 2
}, {
  name: 'bananas',
  quantity: 0
}, {
  name: 'cherries',
  quantity: 5
}, {
  name: 'cherries',
  quantity: 8
}];

function findCherries(fruit) {
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.filter(findCherries));
```